# Using PendingIntent OnFinished callback from a Notification Action

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-pendingintent

Actions in Android Notifications require a PendingIntent to operate.  Typical examples show an action triggering an app Activity.  I'm trying to use a Notification action to open an Android Intent - Rate the app in the play store or send an email.

```
Intent intentRate = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + mThis.getPackageName()))
Intent intentEmail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND ...
```

I would like to make use of the OnFinished PendingIntent callback, but those are called through the .send() method and the syntax for using PendingIntents in Actions don't include .send()

```
Notification.Builder myRatingNotification = new Notification.Builder(mThis)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(text)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .addAction(0, mThis.getString(R.string.Rate_Act_Now), PendingIntent.getActivity(mThis, 0, intentRate, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
                    .addAction(0, mThis.getString(R.string.Rate_App_Email), PendingIntent.getActivity(mThis, 0, intentEmail, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

            Notification notification = new Notification.BigTextStyle(myRatingNotification).bigText(text).build();
            ((NotificationManager) mThis.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).notify(notificationId, notification);
```

This is all running in a BroadcastReceiver service in the background, by the way.  The user would typically never open the app directly except for first-use setup.  So this interaction can only happen via Notification.

How can I get my app to run a little bit of code after the action is chosen and completed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [callback PendingIntent on a notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37436084/callback-pendingintent-on-a-notification)