# callback PendingIntent on a notification

Tags: android

I have an app who is receiving a GCM notification and link to this notification a pendingIntent to open an URL:

```
    private void sendNotification(String message) {
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    Intent intent;

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (url != null) {
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

it works fine but I would like to be informed when this intent is opened (end user click on the notification to open the URL).

I tried to use the OnFinished callback but by doing this:

```
            PendingIntent.OnFinished finish = new PendingIntent.OnFinished() {
            public void onSendFinished(PendingIntent pi, Intent intent,
                    int resultCode, String resultData, Bundle resultExtras) {
                //sending information to Ordolink server as user opened the URL
                ...do my stuff....
            }
        };

        try {
            pendingIntent.send(Activity.RESULT_OK, finish, null);
        } catch (CanceledException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

pendingIntent is opened as soon as the notification is received

I tried by using BroadcastReceiver like this:

my activity:

```
Intent intent_broadcast = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        intent_broadcast.putExtra("url", url);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent_broadcast, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent_broadcast,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

the BroadcastReceiver :

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override

  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("JRE", "Callback onReceive Intent open URL");

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    myIntent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.getStringExtra("url")));

    context.startActivity(myIntent);

  }
```

}

and I also declared the BroadcastReceiver in the Manifest:

```
        <receiver android:name="MyBroadcastReceiver" >
    </receiver>
```

but the MyBroadcastReceiver is never called. any idea ?

Comment: instead of passing Intent.ACTION_VIEW, you can launch an activity or service which would notify your app and then pass the url through Intent.ACTION_VIEW

Comment: You can send one flag with intent like, `intent.putExtra("isFromNotification", true)` and in activity that you are opening on notification click you can check if intent contains `isFromNotification` and if so, app is opened from notification.

Comment: finally by removing `pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent_broadcast,               PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);`it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to use a `BroadcastReceiver` in your app as the `Intent` for `PendingIntent` that would open the URL and in that `BroadcastReceiver` you can know when the user opened the notification.

Example code -

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
Intent intent;

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService (Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

if (url != null) {
    intent = new Intent(context, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("url", url);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
}
```

And in your `BroadcastReceiver` -

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        /* Whatever you want to do */
        ...
        /* Finally open the URL */
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        myIntent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.getStrinExtra("url")));

        context.startActivity(myIntent);
    }

}
```

Comment: do you have any example of implementation ?

Comment: sounds good but startActivity cannot be called from a BroadcastReceiver (sorry if my question is stupid...)

Comment: You can do `context.startActivity(myIntent);`

Comment: Thanks... but MyBroadcastReceiver is never called

Comment: `Intent intent_broadcast = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
   intent_broadcast.putExtra("url", url);

   pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent_broadcast,
     PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
   
   notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);`

Comment: Try with `PendingIntent.getBroadcast`

Comment: same with `pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent_broadcast, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);`